# QGIS Categorized Symbology based on joined table

Tags: qgis, data, symbology, attribute-joins

I am trying to create categorized symbology for a data layer. The column that I would like to base the categories on is a result of a table join. For some reason it isn't working. All of my polygons are blue (see photo). How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell from the info provided, but did you save the dataset to a new vector after you joined?

Comment: Rule based did the trick! I appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad it worked Caleb, I will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug in QGIS where using the **Classify** option for *categorised* and *graduated* styling only outputs a single colour for joined layers (atleast for me as I use QGIS 2.6.1 and I have dozens of joined layers).

A useful workaround is to use **Rule-based** styling as this recognises fields from joined layers and allows you to apply more advanced filters.